# Exporting Excel files from SAP BEx with pivot tables

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-excel, sap-bw

I currently have a report which will be emailed to business users weekly. The data output can only be CSV/XML and I do not have the ability to automatically add the requested pivot tables. Therefore, I am attempting to pull the data with a **Workbook_Open** sub routine which exists in an Excel file.

My issue here is I cannot use Macros on SharePoint nor can the data be publicly accessed in a Macro...so I feel like I am up a creek.

Any suggestions from a VBA, Excel, or BEX/BOBJ standpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if your report is forced to be csv/xml.... and you can't access the data directly through a macro... the solution is not terribly straight forward.

Here is how I would solve

1) SAP Job drops off file

2) Some type of automation kicks off a macro

3) Macro formats and emails report

probably possible to have sap email a spreadsheet formatted to taste directly via abap code.... that is not something i have much experience with.

Comment: Thanks Pynner, I ended us using BOBJ to deliver the report to a web server. On the web server we added a c# console application within the directory of the file. This application opened the file, ran the macro, then sent the file off to a sharepoint team site.Not unlike what you suggested. Again, many thanks.

Comment: So we ended up writing a C# console application that sits on a web server and controlled the process. It went like this:

1. WebI report is delivered through the scheduler to the web server
2. C# console application opens excel sheet, forces it to run a macro (which pulls in csv file delivered by BOBJ) and then saves as itself macroless report in a reports folder.
3. The C# program then iterates through the Reports directory and sends them off to a sharepoint site.
4. The console app is kicked off with the task scheduler.

Hope this helps someone, message me if you would like the source code.